# Как установить OpenCV на DevCpp

Tags: c++, opencv, devc++

И снова здравствуйте. Как установить OpenCV на DevCpp? Я захожу в Сервис->Параметры компилятора->Каталоги: добавляю в "Программы" папку OpenCV\bin, в библиотеки - OpenCV\lib, а в "инклуды" - OpenCV\include. После этого пытаюсь скомпилить данный код:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{

 Mat img(Mat::zeros(300, 300, CV_8U));
 imshow("window", img);
 waitKey();
 return 0;

}
```

Но меня кидает на файл hpp, с огромным кол-ом фраз, что "данной функции не существует". Что я не так подключаю?

Comment: Changes - Version 5.11 - 27 April 2015 - Это последняя версия, ее разработка заброшена. Может стоит подумать о другой ide?

Comment: Что можете порекомендовать нового и нетребовательного к системе? (вижуал не тянет)

Comment: Я пользуюсь Емаксом и просто пишу make файлы.

Comment: попробуйте Code::Blocks, на Raspbian быстро работает, на windows думаю тем более

Comment: Спасибо, попробую...

Comment: Ошибка осталась. Я что-то упускаю...

Comment: Перерыл в интернете всё. В итоге пришёл к тому, что "mutex не элемент класса std". Есть у кого-нибудь подробная инструкция по установке для идиотов?